# Clicking on 5 hotspots reveals a message

Tags: html, hyperlink

I basically have an image with 5 hotspots links on it. I'd like a way of being able to reveal a 'well done' button once all five are clicked. I've looked over Stack, but not found anything that does this. Is there a simple conditional way to do this? Last time I did this was in flash, and it was pretty easy,  but all that coding knowledge is now redundant and I have to start again :(

```
<img src="/park.jpg" width="760" height="500" usemap="#Map" border="0" />
   <map name="Map" id="Map">
   <area shape="rect" coords="40,39,147,95" href="#" />
   <area shape="rect" coords="383,66,534,129" href="#" />
   <area shape="rect" coords="71,209,218,276" href="#" />
   <area shape="rect" coords="460,224,626,282" href="#" />
   <area shape="rect" coords="136,326,511,431" href="#" />
   </map>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need javascript/jquery for this. Here is a little example with jquery.

Jquery:

```
function allclicked() {
    var allclick = true;

    for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
        if(!$("area:eq("+i+")").hasClass("wasclicked")){
            allclick = false;
        }
    }
    if (allclick){
        if ($("#a-wild-div-appeares").length < 1)
            $("body").append("<div id='a-wild-div-appeares'>Content of the div</div>");
    }
};


    $("area").on("click", function(){
        $(this).addClass('wasclicked');
        allclicked();
    });
```

Comment: Is there any way I can get a div tag to appear instead of an alert box?

I changed...

'alert("All areas were clicked");'

to..


'if (allclick){
        $("<div>show</div>").show();'

as I want to get a div to display, but I can't get this to work

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript for this - for each of your areas, you can call a function that sets a variable to indicate that the area has been clicked on (possibly sending an area "id" to distinguish the different areas). This can be done via the `href` attribte on area, using the `javascript:` prefix to call a known function name (with a possible value).

In the event handler you will also test all areas to see if they have been clicked (i.e. their associated variables have been clicked on) and if so - show the success button.